# remote execution of command failing due to sudo issue

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo, sudoers, pam

i am running a command from my server which would remotely ssh to by client machine as root and sudo as olcne user and run few commands for validation.  I have added the olcne user in sudoer list. i am able to locally execute these commands without any issue through sudo but when executed remotely i am getting the below error

```
Apr 18 06:28:02 client sudo:   olcne : user NOT authorized on host ; TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/etc/olcne/scripts/olcne-firewall-check 2379 tcp
Apr 18 06:28:03 client sudo:   olcne : user NOT authorized on host ; TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/etc/olcne/scripts/olcne-image-exists container-registry.oracle.com/olcne/kube-scheduler:v1.14.8


sudoer file

root ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
olcne ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

## Read drop-in files from /etc/sudoers.d (the # here does not mean a comment)
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

cat /etc/sudoers.d/olcne
Cmnd_Alias  OLCNE_PRIVILEGE = \
            /etc/olcne/scripts/
olcne  ALL=(root:ANY)  NOPASSWD: OLCNE_PRIVILEGE
```

Running the command from the client is success.

```
[root@client var]# sudo su olcne -c "sudo /etc/olcne/scripts/olcne-firewall-check 8472 udp"
yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below command from your server.

If script are on source server:

```
ssh olcne@client 'bash -s' < /etc/olcne/scripts/olcne-firewall-check
```

If scripts are on destination server hit the below from source server:

```
ssh user@destinationserver su --session-command="/path/to/command1 arg1 arg2"
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Script  resides on the client and remote execution is done on the client

Comment: Can you please post `/etc/olcne/scripts/olcne-firewall-check` this script & error msg you are getting while executing.